# ListView function - How to let the code "remember" set directory?

Tags: vb.net, listview

So I'm trying to make this Management System for other programs using VB.Net

I asked another question but it was too vague so I'm still stuck.

I got a List View (Which I was recommended to use instead of Listbox) that finds a set of files and extensions in a folder I've chosen in my code (Static, so it finds the same folder each time)

I would like to be able to press "Set.." (A button I already have created and placed) able to open FileDialog, to choose a folder. When pressing OK, the "Application" remembers what folder/directory you were in, so you don't need to set the folder each time.
Also that you can even close down the application, shut down your PC, but the code will still remember what directory/folder you were in, for later use.

```
Code;
```

' This code right here makes the Update button of mine, able to find the files inside the folder/directory. Nothing more. Just refreshes list, as List View is blank when the form is opened.

```
Private Sub updateButtonGame_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles updateButtonGame.Click
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = "xxxx\xxxx\xxxx" Then
        ' List files in the folder.
        ListFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)

    End If
End Sub
```

' This code makes the listview able to find files with multiple Extensions which I need to find.

```
Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal folderPath As String)
    ListViewGame.Items.Clear()

    Dim fi = From f In New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).GetFiles().Cast(Of IO.FileInfo)() _
              Where f.Extension = ".z64" OrElse f.Extension = ".nds" OrElse f.Extension = ".BIN" OrElse f.Extension = ".smc" OrElse f.Extension = ".ISO" OrElse f.Extension = ".nes" OrElse f.Extension = ".gb"
              Order By f.Extension
              Select f

    For Each fileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo In fi
        ListViewGame.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name)
    Next

End Sub
```

So after the Set button has done it's job, and "remember" what directory you pressed OK in, it adds the code to the Update-button code so by pressing Update, it does the same as before.

Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to your settings (Project->Properties->Settings) a new entry called `LastUsedPath` (or whatever you like). This setting should be of type string and user scope. You could also set an initial value that points to your application folder. (".\")

Now in code, everytime you click the button `updateButtonGame` you read this value and set the `FolderBrowserDialog` [SelectedPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) property to this value.
In this way the dialog opens initially to this folder, then, if  the user confirms the selection or change to another directory, you could change the settings to the new path and store it for the next time.

```
using fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog()
    fbd.SelectedPath = My.Settings.LastUsedPath
    If fbd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then 
        ListFiles(fbd.SelectedPath)
        My.Settings.LastUsedPath = fbd.SelectedPath
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If
End Using
```

I suggest also to change the enumeration of file to use the passed variable and not a reference to the FolderBrowserDialog.

```
For Each fileInfo in From f In New IO.DirectoryInfo(folderPath).EnumerateFiles _
          Where f.Extension = ....
```

Notice also that instead of using GetFiles I have changed to EnumerateFiles. This is better because it allows to start the enumeration without loading the whole collection of FileInfo in memory
See [EnumerateFiles remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232(v=vs.110).aspx) section

**EDIT**
My final example was a replacement for your FOR NEXT that populates the ListView. You use mine approach or yours.

```
Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal folderPath As String)
    For Each fi In From f In New IO.DirectoryInfo(folderPath).EnumerateFiles _
      Where f.Extension = ".z64" OrElse f.Extension = ".nds" _
            OrElse f.Extension = ".BIN" OrElse f.Extension = ".smc" _
            OrElse f.Extension = ".ISO" OrElse f.Extension = ".nes" _
            OrElse f.Extension = ".gb"
              Order By f.Extension
              Select f

        ' Remove this line
        ' For Each fileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo In fi

        ListView1.Items.Add(fi.Name)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Steve,
I've worked out the first section (LastUsedPath in properties)
But when ever I add the code to mine, I get multiple errorcodes, red lines under different codes ect,
; http://imgur.com/yOT4adW to see better what I mean.

I'm just trying to take it step by step here.

Know what I should do?

Comment: Wait, I have made this in C#, need to test in VB.NET

Comment: I think I have fixed the answer for VB.NET. Looks also to this article http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/72654-using-settings/

Comment: Right, the updated code works much better. Still getting issues with "fdb" code. and gives me red line. I have 5 "Fixes" from Visual Studio itself. Generate Method Stub, Generate Property Stub, Generate Field, Generate Class or Generate new type..

Comment: Says its not Declared, if that helps.

Comment: The code line that gives Fdb issues is this one;
    fdb.SelectedPath = My.Settings.LastUsedPath

Comment: Character inversion, typing from phone is not easy Sorry. It is fbd

Comment: Well, I am meeting issue after issue, got any contactmethod here, so I can get in direct touch with you other than forum?

Comment: If your project is not too big and you are willing to share you could zip it and upload to a sharing drive like OneDrive, DropBox or GDrive. Then post here the link. I would glad to take a look at it.

Comment: Right, so I uploaded it to GDrive, added for sharing with peeps with the link.

This is not the entire Project, but a project I created with the same codes, I tried your codes, but the project in this file is left with errors. I don't get how to fix it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2g_HxKOjs46ZlQ2NkM1NDZPQ0k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Right, it was that easy.. Slightly embarrassed.
@Steve  Anyway of getting the list to be "auto"populated with the directory content as the form is loaded, instead of haaaving to press update whenever the form starts?

Comment: Use the Form_Load event. Read the current setting for LastUsedPath and call directly the method that populates the listview.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a guide for that? Completely blank here. No idea how to create that method.